# Cinnamon Settings blank after update

Tags: 12.04, updates, cinnamon

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with the cinnamon desktop, I installed the most recent updates and now when I open "System Settings" the entire window appears as a blank white screen. The headers for APPEARANCE, PREFERENCES, and HARDWARE are present, but the usual icons for *Background, *Hot Corners, *Printers, etc. are no longer visible. Some of these settings can still be altered via the terminal:
    cinnamon-settings backgrounds
    cinnamon-settings applets
    cinnamon-settings mouse and touchpad

But other commands, such as `cinnamon-settings hot corners` are met with an error. This is obviously a problem with cinnamon, so I just want to bring it to attention and find out when they plan on fixing the bug. A workaround can be found on the web, but it seems way to risky to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a github bug, now resolved: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2542.
It seems, the fix is not in Ubuntu repos yet, though it is easy to apply manually now: https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/commit/c4eac2e3ab88a2264faedf09f026432522bbe18e.